# Why we could not use the net.sf.json in android?

Tags: android, json

If we use net.sf.json.JSONObejct in android ,the class loader can not find the class .   Why we could not use the net.sf.json in android?
and have a json jar which could use in android ? becuse the org.json of google is too simple . 
i want to parse a JSONObject to/from an Object. 
thxs a lot .

03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at de.bobs_world.mobile.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:67)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-06 14:40:06.613: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, just import the library into your project.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: if i used other json jar,not the org.json, it will occured this error.

Comment: Post the whole exception stack.

Comment: Check net.sf.json dependencies here - http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html - and add missing jars to your build path.

Comment: Ok, I have solved this error. It is becasue of the new adt need not to import jar from Properties > Java Build Path > tab Libraries.   We just build a new folder named libs, and put the jar into this folder, it will recognized the jar automatic.  Thx,you two .  Catherine,Dmitry.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such a problem, the final solution is this: `net.sf.json` needs some other jars, there are [instructions on the official website](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html)

If you want to use `json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar`, you have to add these:

- commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-lang-2.5.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- ezmorph-1.0.6.jar

But when I compile, an exception will be reported:

> multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/collections/Buffer

Violent solutions: Remove the directory of colletions in `commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar`.

Then you can use `net.sf.json` in Android.